# Saving photos to app's cache UWP c#

Tags: c#, caching, camera, uwp

I'm using MediaCapture API for capturing. But I don't know how can I save photos to the app's cache, not to folder at device.

```
private async void btnPhoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // This is where we want to save to.
    var storageFolder = KnownFolders.SavedPictures;

    // Create the file that we're going to save the photo to.
    var file = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

    // Update the file with the contents of the photograph.         
    await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), file);
}
```

User can capture up to five photos and send them to the server and it is necessary don't save photos at the device. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ApplicationData.LocalFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder) to save the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't know how can I save photos to the app's cache, not to folder at device.

I suggest you using [ApplicationData.TemporaryFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241629) to create temporary StorageFile:

```
var file=await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
```

It will create temporary files for cache in disk. And The System Maintenance task will automatically delete these files at any time. User can also delete these files use disk clean up.

If you really don't want to create any file on disk. You can cache the photos using [InMemoryRandomAccessStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), stream);
```

Or save photos to [SoftwareBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn887358(v=win.10).aspx?appid=dev14idef1&l=en-us&k=k(windows.graphics.imaging.softwarebitmap)%3bk(targetframeworkmoniker-.netcore,version%3dv5.0)%3bk(devlang-csharp)&rd=true) if you want to show them in your app:

```
//save the photo to softwareBitmap:
var lowLagCapture = await _mediaCapture.PrepareLowLagPhotoCaptureAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateUncompressed(MediaPixelFormat.Bgra8));
var capturePhoto = await lowLagCapture.CaptureAsync();
SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = capturePhoto.Frame.SoftwareBitmap;
await lowLagCapture.FinishAsync();

//load the image in image tag:
if (softwareBitmap.BitmapPixelFormat != BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8 ||
softwareBitmap.BitmapAlphaMode == BitmapAlphaMode.Straight)
{
    softwareBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
}
var source = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
await source.SetBitmapAsync(softwareBitmap);
mainPageImage.Source = source;//mainPageImage is the image tag name
```